# Function pointer object forward declaration in C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, forward-declaration

I have a group of function pointer objects in a header C++ file, I include this file in the main header file and then trying to use these objects in another C++ file (initialize function pointers and then use these pointers through another part of code) but I always get a "multiple defined" error. Is there a way how to declare global function pointer objects in a header file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in your main header. (Assusming you're using a typedef called FnPointer)

```
extern FnPointer fn;
```

Then in your implementation file

```
FnPointer fn;
```

( `extern` means this variable will exist but I'm going to allocate space for it later in some other compilation unit. )

Comment: Seems I forgot the "extern" keyword after years of C# coding ))). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Just use them like any other global pointers.

- Declare the function pointers as `extern` in one of the header files.
- Include the header in one of the source file that defines the variable &
- Include the header in all the source files that reference the variable.

**Step 1:**

`file.h`

```
extern Func_Pointer ptr1;  /* Declaration of the function pointer */
```

**Step 2:**
`file.cpp`

```
 #include "file.h"  /* Declaration is available through header */  

  /* define it here */ 
  Func_Pointer ptr1 = //some address;
```

**Step 3:**
`someOtherfile.cpp`

```
#include "file.h" 

void doSomething(void) 
{     
    *(ptr1)(); //Use it here
}
```